# How to find why thread is suspended when using multiprocessing or bypass that?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, suspend, feedparser

I use `feedparser` to get rss feeds from some sites, my core code is like this:

```
def parseworker(procnum, result_queue, return_dict, source_link):

    try:
        data = feedparser.parse(source_link)
        return_dict[procnum] = data
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    result_queue.put(source_link + 'grabbed')


def infoworker(procnum, timeout, result_queue, source_name, source_link):

    text = 'recheck ' + source_name + ': ' + '...'
    progress = ''

    for x in range(timeout):
        progress += '.'
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + text + progress)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    result_queue.put('time out')


def parsecaller(link, timeout, timestocheck):

    return_dict = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    counter = 1
    jobs = []
    result = []

    while not (counter > timestocheck):

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=infoworker, args=(11, timeout, result_queue, source_name, link))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=parseworker, args=(22, result_queue, return_dict, link))

    jobs.append(p1)
    jobs.append(p2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    result_queue.get()

    p1.terminate()
    p2.terminate()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    result = return_dict.values()

    if not result or result[0].bozo:
        print(' bad - no data', flush=True)
        result = -1

    else:
        print(' ok ', flush=True)
        result = result[0]
        break

    counter += 1

    if result == -1:
        raise bot_exceptions.ParserExceptionData()
    elif result == -2:
        raise bot_exceptions.ParserExceptionConnection()
    else:
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':

    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')

    try:
        data = parsecaller(source_link, timeout=wait_time, timestocheck=check_times)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        continue
```

It works good, but after some random time goes into suspended state and does nothing - like infinite bootloop. It may suspend after 4 hours or 3 days, that's random.

I try to solve that problem by `multiprocessing`: use main process with timer like **infoworker**. When **infoworker** stops, it will put "result" to queue and by that will call **result_queue.get()** in **parsecaller** which after continues it and terminates both processes. But it does not work. Today, after 11 hours I got my code in suspended state in **multiprocessing managers.py**:

```
def serve_forever(self):
    '''
    Run the server forever
    '''
    self.stop_event = threading.Event()
    process.current_process()._manager_server = self
    try:
        accepter = threading.Thread(target=self.accepter)
        accepter.daemon = True
        accepter.start()
        try:
            while not self.stop_event.is_set():
                self.stop_event.wait(1)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            pass
    finally:
        if sys.stdout != sys.__stdout__: # what about stderr?
            util.debug('resetting stdout, stderr')
            sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
            sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
        sys.exit(0)
```

for all time it was in:

```
            while not self.stop_event.is_set():
                self.stop_event.wait(1)
```

I thing that somewhere or GIL does not allow any other threads to work in processes or feedparser goes into loop. And of course it gets suspended with any random RSS sources.

**My 'environment'**:

- Mac OS 10.12.6 (also was that situation on win7 and win 10)
- Python 3.7.0 (also wat that situation on 3.6.2, 3.6.5)
- Pycharm 2017.2.2

**My questions**:

- How to understand why it gets suspended (what to do, any recipe)?
- How to bypass that state (what to do, any recipe)?

Comment: I'm not sure about how bug-free python 3.7 is. Have you tried using a different version?

Comment: @necko ofcourse, on 3.6.2, 3.6.5 - i went to 3.7.0 because of that problem)